# Overhead: Convert Between Primitive Streams vs. Boxing

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, primitive-types

I'm using the Java 8 Stream API like this:

```
private Function<Long, Float> process;          // Intermediate step (& types)

private long getWeekFrequency(final ScheduleWeek week) {
    return week.doStreamStuff().count();        // Stream<>.count() returns long
}

@Override
public float analyse(final Schedule sample) {
    return (float) sample                       // cast back to float
            .getWeeks()
            .stream()
            .mapToLong(this::getWeekFrequency)  // object to long
            .mapToDouble(process::apply)        // widen float to double
            .sum();
}

@Override
public String explain(final Schedule sample) {
    return sample
            .getWeeks()
            .stream()
            .map(this::getWeekFrequency)        // change stream type?
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

## Questions

- **I assume there is overhead when changing between object/primitive Stream types... How does this compare to the boxing overhead if I stick to Stream<>?**
- **What about if I later change back?**

Concretely:
In analyst, should I use `.map(...).mapToDouble(...)`?
In explain, should I use `.mapToLong(...).mapToObj(...)`?

Comment: I have another question to add: does it matter that much in your system? Do you experience/expect any performance issues from this? "Should I consider just using double/Double everywhere" - what do your business requirements suggest? What does your model look like?

Comment: If this is working code that you wish to improve, the question would likely attract more interesting answers on the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It might however need a rework to include the parts you've simplified as well as the definition of classes involved.

Comment: @Thomas - I'm fairly comfortable with the performance right now (it's sufficient so I value readability). I guess I'm asking more to understand if I'm using `mapToLong()` vs `map()` correctly in the intermediate part of a stream. I'll reword the double/Double bit... that's too open-ended.

Comment: Performance you'll have to measure, but I'd say replacing the analyse() body by a for loop should improve both performance and readability.

Comment: @Aaron - Good suggestion... I hadn't thought to do that. I guess I am really asking if I understand what these things do.

Comment: I've tried to scale the question back to focus on which map methods I should be calling. (sorry Michael... it's supposed to be the same question more clearly expressed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's break this down:

```
.mapToLong(this::getWeekFrequency)
```

gives you a primitive long.

```
.mapToDouble(process::apply)
```

This primitive long is boxed to a `Long` because the `process` function requires it. `process` returns a `Float` which is mapped to a primitive double (via `Float.doubleValue()`).

These are summed and the sum is cast to a primitive float (narrowing, but you say safe) which is then returned.

---

So how can we get rid of some of the autoboxing? We want a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) which exactly matches our `process` function, without using any box classes. There isn't one we can use off-the-shelf, but we can easily define it like so:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface LongToFloatFunction
{
    float apply(long l);
}
```

Then we change our declaration to:

```
private LongToFloatFunction process;
```

and keep everything else the same which will prevent any auto-boxing. The primitive float returned by the function will be automatically widened to a primitive double.

Comment: Thank you Michael; This really helps join the dots of my understanding (in particular being better aware of the primitive `Function` types, and the fact I could create my own primitive->primitive `FunctionalInterface`s where no framework implementation exists)

Comment: In my full context, my process function has some generic logic independent of input type (i.e. I can change Float to float, but I probably want to keep the input param boxed: `float apply(T t)`. In your previous edit you mentioned the OOTB `ToDoubleFunction` which might be more appropriate for me (though perhaps I'll make my own `ToFloatFunction`). Given the input will always be boxed on input to the function, does this mean `.map(myToFloatFunction).mapToDouble(process::apply)` is more efficient? (since the long is boxed anyway and this avoids changing Stream type)

Comment: For most practical purposes, there is no reason for this `LongToFloatFunction` as the already existing `LongToDoubleFunction` is sufficient. For intermediate values, there is rarely a reason to cut them down to the `float` value set, using `float` is useful for *storage* only. This is best illustrated by the fact that there is no `FloatStream` at all, as a *processing* pipeline has no advantage from using `float` instead of `double`. The neat side effect is that you can pass the function directly to `LongStream.mapToDouble` without adapting it via `::apply` then.

Comment: @Holger Good point. I somehow missed that interface when I was checking `java.util.function` (if you check my previous revision, I'd suggested `ToDoubleFunction<Long>`). You're right that that's probably the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems from your definition that `process` looks sort of like this:

```
double process (long value) {
       // do something
}
```

As such if you do : `map(...).mapToDouble` you would be creating an Object of type `Long` every time, only to unbox it immediately after to be used in `process`. I would leave the code as it is to use the primitive implementation that would avoid this.

The second one uses `String#valueOf`. In case of `long`, `String.valueOf(l)` will be called, which works on the primitive: `Long.toString(l)`.

In case of `Object` the same method will be called, *but* with the caveat that first boxing happens. So, I would change it to `mapToLong`

Comment: +1: Thank you for your answer @Eugene; it helps me see the internal steps in more detail. I went with Michael's answer because the added understanding of primitive `Function`s and `FunctionalInterface`s is important to my solution.